# Can the following system of equations be solved analytically/in a closed form?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, fixed-point-theorems

From a constrained non-linear maximization problem I obtained the following system of equations:

$a_1=\frac{1+a_3-\sqrt{a_2a_3}\sqrt{v_1}}{1+\sqrt{\frac{a_3}{a_2}}\sqrt{v_1}}$

$a_2=\frac{2-a_3-\sqrt{(1-a_3)a_1}\sqrt{v_2}}{1+\sqrt{\frac{1-a_3}{a_1}}\sqrt{v_2}}$

$a_3=\frac{2-a_2-\sqrt{(1-a_1)(1-a_2)}\sqrt{v_3}}{1+\sqrt{\frac{1-a_2}{1-a_1}}\sqrt{v_3}}$

All the $v$'s are strictly positive real constants and I only want to consider real, positive closed forms for the $a$'s. More specifically, the $v$'s can be chosen such that $a_i\in(0,1)\ \forall i\in\{1,2,3\}$.

**Edit:** With closed form I mean three expressions for all $a_i$'s that depend only on numbers and $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ or functions of these and simultaneously solve the above system.

Is it possible to say for sure whether or not such a solution exists? I am a little routine-blinded right now and I hoped that someone with a good eye for these problems might come up with a candidate solution.

---

If the question in the title must be answered with a no, might the following be a way of characterizing the solution/ensure its existence:

I could write this system as a recursion $(a_1^{n+1},a_2^{n+1},a_3^{n+1})=F(a_1^n,a_2^n,a_3^n)$. Which condition must be fulfilled by this system in order to verify that there exists a stable (unique) fixed point? I know some results for linear systems, but I fail to search for the right keywords in this case.

Any help is very much appreciated and I am sorry for probably being a little sloppy with terminology.

**Edit:** I already implemented the recursion numerically and it does converge if all $v$'s are sufficiently bounded away from 0 and and $\sim$5. More specifically with 10000 random draws of the vector $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$, all cases converge (with $0<a_i<1$ for all $i$) if the range of these is restricted to $(0.2,5)$ for each component. (Convergence criterion: $10^{-12}$)

Comment: regarding iterative solutions, you are looking for what is called Newton method (or many variants of it): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Nonlinear_systems_of_equations

Comment: it is not clear what you mean when you say that $v$'s can be chosen so that $a_i$'s are 0 or 1. If this is the case, you can just consider that 8 possible choices of $a_i$'s ?

Comment: Regarding both comments I will edit the question to include information on my progress regarding numerical solutions (it's my first post here and I find it hard to select what to include and what is rather unnecessary). Concerning the realizations of the $a_i$'s I meant to say that restricting the $v$'s to a ``reasonable range'' (more details in the edit) can ensure the $a_i$'s to lie in the open unit interval $(0,1)$ so there is infinitely many cases.

Comment: You need to explain what you expect as "closed form" solution.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I edited the first half of the question.